# Dynamically allocated 2 dimensional struct array error

Tags: c

I am having a problem in the following function. I am trying to create a 2 dimensional struct array and assign some values to them. But I get an error saying "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct CoordNode’ from type ‘void *’" error on the double * bracketed line. Thank you.

```
struct CoordNode
{
  double coordX;
  double coordY;
  double coordZ;
  char atomName[3];   
};
void parseCrdList()
{
  int resNum=1;
  int tAtomNum,i;
  char *tcoordX, *tcoordY, *tcoordZ, *tatomName, *tresNum; 
  ccur_node=headCoord_node;  
  struct CoordNode **t;
  t=(struct CoordNode **)malloc(numofRes*sizeof(struct CoordNode *));
  for (i=1;i<=numofRes;i++)
    {
      tAtomNum=0;
      while(i==resNum)
    {
          memmove(tresNum,ccur_node->crdRow+26,4);
          resNum=atoi(tresNum);
      **t[i-1][tAtomNum]=malloc(sizeof(struct CoordNode));**
          memmove(tcoordX,ccur_node->crdRow+35,7);
          memmove(tcoordY,ccur_node->crdRow+43,7);
          memmove(tcoordZ,ccur_node->crdRow+51,7);
          memmove(tatomName,ccur_node->crdRow+17,3);
          t[i-1][tAtomNum].coordX=strtod(tcoordX,NULL);
          t[i-1][tAtomNum].coordY=strtod(tcoordY,NULL);
          t[i-1][tAtomNum].coordZ=strtod(tcoordZ,NULL);
          t[i-1][tAtomNum].atomName=malloc(4*sizeof(char));
          strcpy(t[numofRes-1][tAtomNum],tatomName);
          old_ccur_node=ccur_node;
          ccur_node=ccur_node->next;
          free(old_ccur_node);
          tAtomNum++;
          if (ccur_node==NULL)
        break;
    }
      if (maxAtomNum<tAtomNum)      
    maxAtomNum=tAtomNum+1;
    }
    addCoordData(t);
}
```

Comment: `type **t` is pointer to pointer of `type`. t[index] is pointer of `type`. t[index1][index2] is `type`.

Comment: t[index1][index2] is not an array element?

Comment: t[index1][index2] is an array element. it is not pointer. malloc returned pointer(void*).

Comment: This is exactly why you must never cast the result of malloc (as you do on the first malloc in your code)